# How to listen for file open event in windows OS level using node js

Tags: node.js, windows, electron

I am developing an electron application in which there is a need to watch a directory so whenever  user opens a file from that directory there should be a event triggered in my application getting path and name of that file

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the direct method for doing this.
But you can enable auditing option for a particular folder and check the windows logs for the particular folder and trigger the event.
please refer the website : [windows folder auditing steps](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-xp/how-to-track-and-monitor-who-and-when-someone-accesses-a-folder-on-your-computer/)

then access the logs from your application and find the required logs for that folder

use "windows-eventlog-reader" for accessing the required logs.
 refer : 
[windows-eventlog-reader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-eventlog-reader)